# document.onpageshow is not a function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I've the following javascript file:

```
onShowFunction = function(e){
   //Some JQuery code
}
window.onpageshow(onShowFunction);
```

The index console log appears:

```
[Error] TypeError: window.onpageshow is not a function. 
(In 'window.onpageshow(onShowFunction)', 'window.onpageshow' is null)
Global Code (scripts.js:58)
```

I don't understand how to resolve. Is that event defined in other way and it is not a function?

Comment: window.onpageshow is not a function , mean you have to assign your created function to this window variable like `window.onpageshow = onShowFunction`

Comment: Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/pageshow)

Answer (score 5):

window.onpageshow is not default js function.
Try this:

```
window.addEventListener('pageshow', function(event) {
    console.log('pageshow:');
    console.log(event);
});
```

In your case:

```
window.addEventListener('pageshow', onShowFunction);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
window.addEventListener('pageshow', onShowFunction);
```

or

```
window.onpageshow = function(e) { //Some JQuery code }
```

or

```
<body onpageshow="onShowFunction(e)"></body>
```